# intrinsically sizing from core data (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I have a name label in a cell that is intrinsically sized so that the left anchor of the time label may always be 5 pixels from the left anchor of the name label. However when I introduce names from core data, it takes the initial setup name and uses that name to intrinsically size the name label frame.

Here is where I create the label view.

```
let nameLabel: UILabel = {
    let nlabel = UILabel()
    nlabel.text = "Barack Obama"
    nlabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
    nlabel.textAlignment = .left
    nlabel.frame.size = nlabel.intrinsicContentSize

    nlabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    print("nlabel frame \(nlabel.frame.size)")

    return nlabel
}()
```

nlabel.text for each cell is equal to cell?.friend?.name

I am successfully able to load the names into the cell however the frame is still sized as if nlabel.text was equal to the first nlabel.text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you literally setting the text to "Barack Obama" for every nLabel you create? Or is your actual code using the name from Core Data?

Comment: the code is using the names from core data. "Barack Obama" was what I used as the first set up cells name because I couldn't leave it nil.

Comment: That's a problem. Are you using Auto Layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Auto Layout, remove this line:

```
    nlabel.frame.size = nlabel.intrinsicContentSize
```

And add this line:

```
    nlabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

With Auto Layout, you must not set the frame size yourself.

You are giving the same size to every label you create. The size is not going to change just because you change the text it contains.

Labels have intrinsic size, but when you create labels in code, not the storyboard, you need to set translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints to false in order for this to work. When you create labels in the storyboard, this is done for you automatically.

For more info, see https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco?language=objc